# SQL Procedure to pass in two lists with values, lookup the combination in a table and return array?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have two arrays in python which I would like to send into an SQL Stored Procedure, have the combinations looked up in a table and then return the rows that match. For example:

```
Serial_no = ['100', '200', '300']
date = ['2022-03-20', '2022-03-21', '2022-03-22']
```

It would look up table under table 'A' the following combinations:

```
(Serial_no = '100', date = '2022-03-20')
(Serial_no = '200', date = '2022-03-21')
(Serial_no = '300', date = '2022-03-22')
```

If there is a match it will return the row from table A. Is there an efficient way to do this? I am using a memsql database.

Comment: Is it always the first serial number with the first date, second serial number with second date, and so on? Or could they be combined in any order?

Comment: Do you have to do this in a MySQL procedure. It's easier to do these loops in Python.

Comment: @Barmar They have to be in the specific order so the i'th serial number with i'th date.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately I have to do it in SQL as I don't want to make multiple calls to the SQL database. Just one call with both lists and return the data.

Comment: You don't need multiple calls to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Do this by constructing the query dynamically in Python rather than a MySQL stored procedure.

```
placeholders = ','.join(['(%s, %s)'] * len(Serial_no))
sql = f'SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE (serial_no, date) IN ({placeholders})'
params = zip(serial_no, date)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

The first two lines create `sql` that looks like

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE (serial_no, date) IN ((%s, %s), (%s, %s), (%s, %s), ...)
```

with enough placeholders for all the elements of the two lists. Then `zip()` pairs up the serial numbers and dates in the `params` argument to `cursor.execute()`.